# isakmp / ike not listening on port 500

Tags: ipsec

I just updated to 20.04 LTS, and installed the strongswan things.
I copied a configuration that works on a Debian 10 system (and made some changes to reflect this system).

When I do "ipsec restart" and then "netstat - u -l -n" I don"t see anything listening on port 500 and port 4500.
On the Debian 10 system, there is clearly something listening on these ports.

Also, I have no idea where I can find any usefull logs on the Ubuntu system.

Anybody any idea what could be wrong?

Much thanks in advance!

Greetings.